# "client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe" for chroot sftp user, with correct password?

Tags: ssh, sshd, chroot

I am in the process of setting chroot for sftp and have used a combination of tutorials ([source1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-16-04), [source2](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/)) and have ended up with the following configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match Group sftpusers
      ForceCommand internal-sftp
      ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/
      PermitTunnel no
      AllowAgentForwarding no
      AllowTcpForwarding no
      X11Forwarding no
```

The sftp base folder is `/var/sftp` and the user was created as follows:

```bsh
groupadd sftpusers

adduser myuser01
mkdir -p /var/sftp/myuser01
usermod -a -G sftpusers myuser01
chown myuser01:myuser01 /var/sftp/myuser01
systemctl restart sshd
```

Now when I try a login I end up in the `/var/sftp` folder, which demonstrates login works.

Since I want users to end up in the `/var/sftp/<userid>` folder, I try setting the following config is `sshd_config`, under the `Match Group` line :

```
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/%u
```

When I do that I get an error `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe` on a login attempt. According to the man page for `ssh_config` the variable should be accepted, per:

> ChrootDirectory accepts the tokens %%, %h, and %u.

Any ideas?

Env:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- sshd: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

Answer (score 13):

```
chown myuser01:myuser01 /var/sftp/myuser01
...
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/%u
```

The OpenSSH SSH server's [ChrootDirectory](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory) directive requires that the chroot directory and its parent directories be owned by root:

> **ChrootDirectory**
> Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication. **At session startup sshd(8) checks that all components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are not writable by any other user or group.** After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

I haven't tested this, but I *think* that if you create a `/etc/passwd` file within the chroot environment, containing a line for the user in question, then sshd will honor the home directory field in that line as the user's home directory within the chroot environment. If this actually works, then you could use this to have the user's session start with its working directory somewhere other than the chroot directory.

Comment: Both `/var` & `/var/sftp` are owned by root

Comment: `/var/sftp/myuser01` is the directory that you're trying to use as the chroot directory, and it's not owned by root.

Comment: Changing ownership to root changes the login issue, but now the user can't upload a file, since they don't own the folder. What do I deal with that one?

Comment: You create directories within the chroot directory with permissions/ownership that allow the user to create files.

Comment: ok, so I just created an 'uploads' folder with ownership on the user and that works - thanks, though it does mean you example is probably not correct. The chown there would need to be root, with a folder inside belonging to the user.

Comment: The contents of the code block in my answer was copied from your question. It's not a suggestion of what you should do.

Comment: `chroot directory and its parent directories be owned by root` saved my ass when I inadvertently broke production

Answer (score 5):

In your example, `/var/sftp` and `/var/sftp/usero1` needs to be owned by `root` and not writable by any other user

your issue is likely that you did this:

```
chown myuser01:myuser01 /var/sftp/myuser01
```

instead it should be owned by `root:root` and `chmod 755`

```
sudo mkdir /var/sftp
sudo mkdir /var/sftp/myuser01
sudo chown -R root:root /var/sftp
chmod -R 755 /var/sftp
```

Now that the user directory is owned by `root:root` and not writable by others, your user should be able to be logged into it and chrooted via the sshd internal-sftp

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/
```

So, to put it all together:

```
sudo groupadd sftpusers

sudo mkdir /var/sftp
sudo mkdir /var/sftp/myuser01
sudo chown -R root:root /var/sftp
chmod -R 755 /var/sftp

sudo adduser -h /var/sftp/myuser01 myuser01
sudo usermod -a -G sftpusers myuser01
```

edit your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add this to the end:

```
Match Group sftpusers
      ForceCommand internal-sftp
      ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/%u
      PermitTunnel no
      AllowAgentForwarding no
      AllowTcpForwarding no
      X11Forwarding no
```

Then after saving restart sshd

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

My issue with this was that it meant that the user "myuser01" would not have any write access to their base directory... so in my case this isn't too bad - I actually needed "myuser01" to have a www directory which they needed access to - I solved this by

```
sudo mkdir /var/sftp/myuser01/www/
sudo chown myuser01:myuser01 /var/sftp/myuser01/www/
```

(changed names to follow your naming convention here)

This will work if all you want is to make an SFTP chroot jail for that user - they will only be able to use SFTP but you don't need to go and build a whole chrooted set of commands and libs for them to use... Otherwise you need to go and add the needed commands to their bin directory as well as needed libs to their `/lib` directory, and I think a local copy of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` with the needed group and user entries (I've not tested this myself yet as I just needed an SFTP chroot jail)

Comment: This is the REAL answer. chroot directory will NOT work if is owned by user, needs to be owned by root.

Comment: what is -h switch for in adduser command?   seems typo

Comment: khalidmehmoodawan

The -h is for home directory.  I'll admit it was a while ago when I wrote this and perhaps it was a typo - you could use

--home in place of my -h

Answer (score 0):

The ChrootDirectory must contain the necessary files and directories to support the user's session.  For an interactive session this requires at least a shell, typically sh(1), and
basic /dev nodes such as null(4), zero(4), stdin(4), stdout(4), stderr(4), and tty(4) devices.  **For file transfer sessions using SFTP no additional configuration of the environmentis necessary if the in-process sftp-server is used**, though sessions which use logging may require /dev/log inside the chroot directory on some operating systems (see sftp-server(8) for details).

Answer (score 0):

**The following worked for me. Below is just an example.**

- Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and modify and enable this line as below

  ```
  Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
  ```
- Then go to end of file (or modify if already existing). SFTP base folder will be `/home/sftp`

  ```
  Match Group sftpusers
      ChrootDirectory /home/sftp
      ForceCommand internal-sftp
      X11Forwarding no
      AllowTcpForwarding no
  ```
- Save the file and restart ssh service

  ```
  systemctl restart sshd
  ```

Then execute the following commands. `sftpuser` will be our user; `sftpusers` will be our group, so in future

- just create new user for SFTP and add to `sftpusers`.

  ```
  useradd -d /home/sftp -s /bin/false -g users -G sftpusers sftpuser
  ```
- set the password of `sftpuser`

  ```
  passwd sftpuser
  ```
- execute the following lines

  ```
  chown root:root /home/sftp
  #rights for group & others chmod go+rx /home/sftp
  mkdir /home/sftp/{upload,download}
  chown sftpuser:users /home/sftp/{upload,download}
  chown sftpuser:sftpusers /home/sftp/{upload,download}
  ```

Now, you can verify SFTP from any remote server or SFTP client:

```
sftp sftpuser@10.110.20.30
```

Comment: `#rights for group & others chmod go+rx /home/sftp` using that breaks it

Comment: may be you can explain it further and I can improve the answer @xeruf . i saw ur message today after months . sorry